# Git rebase multiple commits in one branch to the master

Tags: git

When I read the rebase command in git documentation, I have a question.
Is it possible to rebase the three commit  x x x in topic 'next' to master?

```
  o---o---o---o---o  master
           \
            o---o---x---x---x  next
```

rebase to

```
  o---o---o---o---o---x---x---x  master
           \
            o---o  next
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You really need two steps here.  First do a `rebase --onto` to bring the top 3 commits from `next` onto `master`:

```
master:  o1 -- o2 -- o3 -- o4 -- o5
                       \
next:                   o6 -- o7 -- x1 -- x2 -- x3
```

Use:

```
git rebase --onto o5 o7
```

Then, remove the top 3 commits from the `next` branch:

```
# from next
git reset --hard HEAD~3
```

Comment: nice `git rebase --onto o5 o7`!

Answer (score 3):

for this purpose I would look at

`git cherry-pick` for the new commits on `master`

and

`git reset --hard` for clearing those commits on `next`

a script might look like this:

```
git switch master
git cherry-pick next~2 next~1 next~0
git switch next
git reset --hard HEAD~3
```

Comment: Bear in mind that the `o` commits might alter what the `x` commits actually do, so you may not end up with what you expect or you'll have to do some manual editing to get them right